# Node export import into different node numbers

Tags: importing-exporting

I use [node export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export) to export my nodes from Drupal 6 and import into my new site Drupal 7.

The nodes number is not same with nodes in Drupal 6.

How do I set it same as nodes number in Drupal 6.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Node ID numbers is an auto-incremented field in the database that is global for the entire Drupal installation. Attempting to replicate the exact Node ID in Drupal can be difficult and cause serious problems if handled incorrectly.

If your issue is URLs, one option is to make a 301 alias for the old URLs to the new URLs. There are modules to easily create the redirects like the [Redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect).

If you must maintain the ID numbers then the solution will have to be custom migration code. The migration process will recreate the nodes in the new site and account for any node deletions.

Comment: I have thousand of article. It is hard for me to change every article node ID numbers.

Comment: @JasonJason Yes this is not an easy problem to fix. For your future knowledge, never use node/ID as a path on a site. Use Pathauto and Global Redirect to create all your URLs on your site. Then you don't care what the node ID is.